# Problem with Strpos In PHP

Tags: php, string, strpos

I'm writing a simple function and for some reason(probably a simple one) it's not working for me and I was wondering if you guys could help me out.

```
function check_value($postID) 
    {
        $ID = $postID;
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['list_of_IDS'];
        $position = strpos($cookie,$ID);
        echo 'ID:'.$ID.'-Cookie:'.$cookie;
            if ($position !== false)
        {
            echo "ID is in the cookie";
        }
    }
```

In trying to figure out what the problem was I put that echo line above the If Statement there to make sure there actually is stuff in the variables.

My problem is that the IF statement never prints out.

A `$postID` is a number `123123`.

The `$cookie` string is usually something like `123123.23422.234234.2342342.234234`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strpos won't work with an int, so you need to cast the ID to a string.  Try this:

```
$ID = (string)$postID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!   Knew it was going to be something stupidly obvious...

Answer (score 2):

Note that if your cookie string looks like `123123.23422.234234.2342342.234234` and you are looking for an ID, say, `1231` or `23`, your function would return `TRUE` while actually that ID is not in the list. Your current implementation of `strpos()` will also match partial numbers.

Here is a simple workaround that will require the ID to be surrounded by dots.

```
$position = strpos('.'.$cookie.'.', '.'.$ID.'.');
```

Answer (score -2):

yes as Brock said Strpos wont work with an int so you have to cast the id.
so need some change in your code.

```
function check_value($postID) 
    {
        $ID = $postID;
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['list_of_IDS'];
        $position = strpos($cookie,$ID);
        echo 'ID:'.$ID.'-Cookie:'.$cookie;
            if ($position !== false)
        {
                echo "ID is in the cookie";
        }
    }
```