# Unexpected PHP Array key behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

Ok I find this very weird but there should be an explanation. Here is what happens.

This code here should echo nothing:

```
$str = 'a@gmail.com';
$key = '11111';
echo strpos($str, $key);
exit;
```

.. and yes this is exactly what I get, nothing. But !!
If I am to use the $key (which contains a string) as an actual key of an array:

```
$str = 'a@gmail.com';
$arr = array('11111' => 'test');
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    echo 'String: '.$str.'<br>';
    echo 'Key: '.$key.'<br>';
    echo 'Found at position: '.strpos($str, $key);
}
exit;
```

I get this amazing, magical result:

```
String: a@gmail.com
Key: 11111
Found at position: 2
```

So what php found here was the string `11111` to be the letter `g`
But what is even more amazing, is that the number of digits changes the result:

```
$str = 'a@gmail.com';
$arr = array('111' => 'test');
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    echo 'String: '.$str.'<br>';
    echo 'Key: '.$key.'<br>';
    echo 'Found at position: '.strpos($str, $key);
}
exit;
```

This one gives:

```
String: a@gmail.com
Key: 111
Found at position: 9
```

Any experts on this ?
Thank you.

EDIT:
This is actual code example used in my project which gives such false positives:

```
$email = '[the email of the user here]';
$arr = array(
    // [...]
    '11111' => 'Banned',
    '22222' => 'Banned',
    '33333' => 'Banned',
    // [...]
);
foreach ($arr as $key => $reason)
{
    if (strpos($email, (string)$key) !== false)
    {
        return 'Keyword: '.(string)$key.' found in the user Email address with reason: '.(string)$reason;
    }
}
```

So even using the (string) in front of the variable `$key` it bans innocents at the login form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Strpos In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039738/problem-with-strpos-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this, It will work fine. I type casted `$key` into `string`. PHP function [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for matching substring with in the string, not the integer value. If you look into the documentation, it is clearly mentioned

**Second parameter:** `If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$str = 'a@gmail.com';
$arr = array('11111' => 'test');
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    echo 'String: '.$str.'<br>';
    echo 'Key: '.$key.'<br>';
    echo 'Found at position: '.strpos($str, (string)$key);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, well this is exactly what I am doing in my project's code loop but it still hits this false positive. So again, the question is, WHY is this happening without or even WITH the (string) before the `$key` ? It is funny !

Comment: @durduvakis Please check my current code, if it is still not working, then please share that code in your post which is not working.

Comment: If you notice it is a string once it is in single quotes.

Comment: yes i see,but in itself `strpos` is treating it as integer, so if you type cast it into `string` It will start working the way you want.

Comment: right, give me a moment to find my code exactly at that point which banned a user an hour ago due to this false positive.

Comment: @durduvakis Okay no issues, take your time.

Comment: please check my updated question at the end. The code is very similar to the original examples I gave.

Comment: @durduvakis can you provide that email id, a sample one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141930/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-durduvakis).